# Reading Excelsheets using openpyxl and Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have a folder with >1000 .xlsx-files containing data. I want to merge all that data into one sheet to process it further. Every .xlsx-file has 4 sheets called (Sheet 1, Sheet 2, Sheet 3 and Data). As the Excel-files always evolve, the sheet Data is always updated to the newest version. Reason behind is that for example when we change the layout, all data-sheets are identical to process. The data-sheet points to the other sheets in order to summarize the needed data.

Before starting to merge all the data, I want to update to the latest version of the data-sheet. For this I have a Template.xlsx in which there is a data-sheet. I have this code:

```
WorkbookTemplate=openpyxl.load_workbook(Template.xlsx)
if "Data" in WorkbookTemplate.sheetnames:
    WorkSheetTemplate=WorkbookTemplate["Data"]
```

My problem is that my python script needs to run in UTF-8. The "Data"-sheet in the template cannot be found since, I have always the UTF-8 prefix in the sheetnames:

```
print(str(WorkbookTemplate.sheetnames))
```

which gives me:

```
[u'Sheet 1', u'Sheet 2', u'Sheet 3', u'data']
```

How can I overcome this situation, so that the "Data"-Worksheet is found?

Comment: This has nothing to do with UTF-8 as sheetnames are all unicode. Your problem is that sheetnames are **case** sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Charlie Clark:
the sheetnames are case sensitive! This solved the issue.